# Replacing SimpleFormController in Spring v3.1

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to write some basic example from springsource.org and also to replace SimpleFormController in example to some @Controller and @RequestMapping annotations. But all I get when application is running is error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'priceIncrease' available as request attribute`

Here is some code, in .jsp I have this:

```
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="priceIncrease">
 <table width="95%" bgcolor="f8f8ff" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
 <tr>
   <td align="right" width="20%">Increase (%):</td>
     <td width="20%">
      <form:input path="percentage"/>
     </td>
     <td width="60%">
      <form:errors path="percentage" cssClass="error"/>
     </td>
 </tr>
</table>
<br>
<input type="submit" align="center" value="Execute">
</form:form>
```

and the Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/priceincrease.htm")
public class PriceIncreaseFormController {

@Autowired
PriceIncreaseValidator priceIncreaseValidator; 

protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

@RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.POST)
public String onSubmit(@ModelAttribute("priceIncrease")PriceIncrease priceIncrease,   BindingResult result) throws ServletException {

    int increase = priceIncrease.getPercentage();
    priceIncreaseValidator.validate(increase, result);

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "priceIncrease";
    }

    logger.info("Increasing prices by " + increase + "%.");

    return "redirect:home.htm";
  }

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String initializeForm(ModelMap model) {
    Map<Integer, String> priority = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();

    priority.put(1, "low");
    priority.put(2, "medium");
    priority.put(3, "high");

    model.addAttribute("priorityList", priority);

    return "priceincrease";

  }
}
```

As far as I know, I don't need any additional configuration in servlet.xml, am I right? So do you know guys where's the problem?

@kmb385
thanks for help, now the form initializes correctly, but also there is another problem with 'onSubmit' and validate method. Right now the code looks like this:

```
@Autowired
PriceIncreaseValidator priceIncreaseValidator; 

protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

@Autowired
private ProductManager productManager;

@RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.POST)
public String onSubmit(@ModelAttribute("priceIncrease")PriceIncrease priceIncrease, BindingResult result) throws ServletException {

    int increase = priceIncrease.getPercentage();
    logger.info("Increasing prices by " + increase + "%.");

    logger.info("result : " + result.toString());
    priceIncreaseValidator.validate(increase, result);

    productManager.increasePrice(increase);

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "priceIncrease";
    }



    return "redirect:hello.htm";
}
```

and in

```
priceIncreaseValidator.validate(increase, result);
```

glassfish returns

```
    org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

PriceIncreaseValidator:

```
public class PriceIncreaseValidator implements Validator {

private int DEFAULT_MIN_PERCENTAGE = 0;
private int DEFAULT_MAX_PERCENTAGE = 50;
private int minPercentage = DEFAULT_MIN_PERCENTAGE;
private int maxPercentage = DEFAULT_MAX_PERCENTAGE;

@Override
public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
    return PriceIncrease.class.equals(clazz);

}

@Override
public void validate(Object arg0, Errors arg1) {
    PriceIncrease pi = (PriceIncrease) arg0;

    if (pi == null) {
        arg1.rejectValue("percentage", "error.not-specified", null, "cos wymagane");
    }
    else {
        if (pi.getPercentage() > maxPercentage) {
            arg1.rejectValue("percentage", "error.too-high", new Object[] {new Integer(maxPercentage)}, "za duzo");
        }
        if (pi.getPercentage() <= minPercentage) {
            arg1.rejectValue("percentage", "error.too-low", new Object[] {new Integer(minPercentage)}, "za malo");
        }
    }

}

public void setMinPercentage(int i) {
    this.minPercentage = i;
}

public int getMinPercentage() {
    return minPercentage;
}

public void setMaxPercentage(int i) {
    this.maxPercentage = i;
}

public int getMaxPercentage() {
    return maxPercentage;
}
```

}

Do you have any idea what's now wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an attribute of type `PriceIncrease` with the name `priceIncrease` to the model when initializing the form.

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String initializeForm(ModelMap model) {
    Map<Integer, String> priority = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();
    priority.put(1, "low");
    priority.put(2, "medium");
    priority.put(3, "high");

    PriceIncrease priceIncrease = new PriceIncrease();  //Not sure of constructor
    model.addAttribute("priceIncrease", priceIncrease);

    model.addAttribute("priorityList", priority);

    return "priceincrease";

  }
}
```